# What happens if you call close() on a BSD socket multiple times

Tags: c, sockets

Is it safe to call close() on a BSD sockets `socketfd` multiple times?

Comment: I think it's undefined behavior, but note that the file descriptor might have been reused in the mean time for a new file. So at the very least the possible behavior includes, "closing someone else's stream, which they really didn't expect".

Comment: OK, so I'm wrong that it's UB. The implementation is required to validate the input. Just make sure you haven't created any new file descriptors between the two calls to close.

Comment: @SteveJessop: The OP should also make sure no library creates any new file descriptor, which may not be so obvious. IOW, programmers shouldn't go around willy-nilly `close()`ing unknown file descriptors; programmers should know what they are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you'll get an `EBADF` if the file descriptor isn't being (re)used for anything after its initial close.

It's common practice to assign an invalid number to the fd after it's been close. A common idiom to use

```
 close(fd);
 fd = -1;
```

should be the idiom to use. This way, closing the socket again will result in a silent `EBADF` and not clobber the state of newly assigned valid file descriptors.

(Note the 'invalid file handle' value might be different on other platforms.. i.e. windows (?); but should work on any POSIX system).

Answer (score 3):

From the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close):

> `close()` returns zero on success.  On error, `-1` is returned, and `errno` is set appropriately.
>
> ERRORS
>
> ```
>   EBADF  fd isn’t a valid open file descriptor.
> ```

So it stands to reason that the `close` call will fail with the above error. (Which is indeed what happens on my machine.)

Comment: Unless, as Steve commented, that file descriptor has been re-opened as something else in the meantime...

Comment: @twalberg: well, yes. I hope that wasn't going to be the OP's confusion.

Comment: It's not necessarily obvious when and how file descriptors are reused. I reckon I could get confused on that point, if I put my mind to it :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Well, it's certainly possible to duplicate FDs and replicate them across processes, but in any event, the numeric variable refers to a kernel object that is either an open FD or not. If it isn't, then you get an error, but there's nothing undefined about it. So in that sense it's certainly "safe".